# Download file feature for all browser in angular 6. Works fine with chrome and all but not in IE. What am I missing?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, download, angular6, blob

I have to create a download link in angular 6 that should work in all browser. It works fine with chrome, fire fox but not in IT. I created the blob and changes mumeType too. I might be missing somehting. 
Code is below for IE download.

---

**HTML code**

```
<a *ngIf="true" class="link-dwnld" download="{{log.createdBy+'_'+(log.createDate | regexpReplace: '^(.*)Z$': '$1'| date: 'MMddyy_HHmm')+'.csv'}}"
                   [href]="downloadLinkI" (click)="getInputFileIE(log.overpaymentRecoveryId)">
                  {{log.createdBy+'_'+(log.createDate | regexpReplace: '^(.*)Z$': '$1'| date: 'MMddyy_HHmm')+'.csv'}}
                </a>
```

---

**ts file code**

```
> getInputFileIE(id: number): boolean {
>     console.log('from IE download. its IE');
>     this.recoveryLog.forEach( dataStr => {
>       if (dataStr.overpaymentRecoveryId === id) {
>         this.strI = dataStr.inputFile ;
>         this.strO = dataStr.outputFile;
>       }
>     });
>     const strMimeType = 'application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8';
>     // IE10+
>     if (navigator.msSaveBlob && this.strI) {
>       return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob(['\ufeff', this.strI], {
>         type: strMimeType
>       }), this.fileNameI);
>     } else if (navigator.msSaveBlob && this.strO) {
>       return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob(['\ufeff', this.strO], {
>         type: strMimeType
>       }), this.fileNameO);
>     }
>     return true;   }
```

Comment: What's your IE browser version? Try to use IE Browser F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Then, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)) to save files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob.

Comment: this file is helpful thanks!  Although my non browser code I copied to this method worked for now. Thought I haven't tested it accurately so can't be 100% sure. I am going to try this article example as well.